# Android MVP - What is the correct way to handle onActivityResult?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, onactivityresult, android-mvp

`onActivityResult` should be delegated to the `Presenter`. Then the `Presenter` should decide what to do with the result. The question is how to do it in the clean way?

There is an example app in Google samples:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvp-dagger/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/tasks/TasksFragment.java#L115-L118

It delegates the result to the `Presenter`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    mPresenter.result(requestCode, resultCode);
}
```

But there is a **bug** in this solution. The `Presenter` drops the `View` (in this case the `Fragment`) in `onDestroy()` method:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mPresenter.dropView();  
}
```

And takes the `View` in `onResume()` method:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mPresenter.takeView(this);
}
```

When we open new activity for the result. Then rotate the phone, then finish current activity and come back to the first one, the `Presenter` won't have the `View` because `onActivityResult` will be called before `onResume`.

```
D/TasksFragment: onCreate
D/TasksFragment: onCreateView
D/TasksFragment: onStart
D/TasksFragment: onResume
--- open new activity for the result ---
D/TasksFragment: onPause
D/TasksFragment: onStop
--- rotate the phone ---
--- finish current activity ---
D/TasksFragment: onDestroy
D/TasksFragment: onCreate
D/TasksFragment: onCreateView
D/TasksFragment: onStart
D/TasksFragment: onActivityResult (called before onResume)
D/TasksFragment: onResume
```

Comment: add mPresenter.takeView(this); instead to oncreate method

Comment: a better approach is to use  architecture components based on mvvm design pattern .in this approach you don't need to handle anything related to android lifecycle